# How does the pow(builtin not math module) function in Python work?

Tags: python, modulo

How exactly does the pow built-in function in python work? Specifically, how does it compute (a^b)%c. What is the algorithm?

```
>>>pow(134562,12345,15)
12
```

whereas the naive,

```
>>>(134562**12345)%15
```

isn't able to yield anything even after a significant amount of time. What optimisation is performed that leads to the massive speed up?

Comment: Probably one of the techniques listed on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the link. Is there anyway I can view the source code for python's implementation? I mean yeah it's open source so there is, but where can I find it?

Comment: @Sabyasachi Somewhere on http://hg.python.org/cpython/ (make sure to pick the relevant branch).